# Having problems with fgetc while reading file

Tags: c, c99

I am trying to read a text file into an 2D array (row/column). When the file reads a newline, I want to fill the remainder of the array row with the space value (ASCII 32).
It seems the section of code where the file value is read using fgetc is causing my code to behave weird.

I will post my code below:

```
val = 0; fill = 0;
while(val != EOF && i < WORLDHEIGHT)
{
   if(val==10)
   {
       fill = 1;
   }

   if(fill==1)
   {
       world[i][j] = 32;
   }
   else
   {
       val=fgetc(fd);
       world[i][j] = val;
   }
   j++;

   if(j > WORLDWIDTH)
   {
       i++;
       j=0;
       fill = 0;
       val = 0;
       printf("reached WORLDWIDTH:i=%d j=%d val=%d fill=%d\n", i,j,val,fill);
   }
}
```

The program does not seem to reach the last if statement.  If I comment out the line "val = 0" then it does reach it otherwise it will not.

Can anyone explain why this is?  Thank you.

Comment: What type is `val`? And (use [edit] on your question) please remove either the C or the C ++ tag.

Comment: `j > WORLDWIDTH` --> `j >= WORLDWIDTH` ?

Comment: Why not fill the array with `32` before you begin to read from file?

Comment: Please use `' '` instead of 32 to represent a space.  It is (marginally) more portable and a lot clearer.  Similarly with `'\n'` and 10.

Comment: "*The program does not seem to reach the last if statement.*" -- This is not a program; it's a program fragment. There's no `#include <stdio.h>`, no `main` function, no definition of *any* variables. Read this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: thank you all, figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally,

- With `val = 0`, the `while` loop stopped by condition `val != EOF`,
  you will stop filling when it reach EOF (the end of the file).
- Without `val = 0`, the `while` loop stopped by condition `i < WORLDHEIGHT`,
  you will continue filling until the entire array filled with 32.

P.S. You can also put your `printf` in front of `i++` to log.

```
 if(j > WORLDWIDTH)
   {
       printf("reached WORLDWIDTH:i=%d j=%d val=%d fill=%d\n", i,j,val,fill);
       i++;
       j=0;
       fill = 0;
       val = 0;
       //printf("reached WORLDWIDTH:i=%d j=%d val=%d fill=%d\n", i,j,val,fill);
   }
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks for point it out. Is it just a problem about print place?

Comment: probably, memory overwrite is happening  somewhere in the program.